# In cycles material how to get stencil effect similar to blender internal material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I want to achieve fallowing stencil effect using cycles mix nodes in **single cycles** material

[image]

[Images of eye shape and dot i have mentioned in the screen shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jpq2cgNh8zMnpaQS1JaVFBRHM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With trial and error I got this result, which is what I was looking for. The two images are mixed based on the pupil image's alpha channel, overlaying it onto the eye image. Next the eyes are mixed with the background using the eye texture's alpha channel.

[image]

Comment: That is the correct way to do that.

Comment: +1 Nice comeback, Algebraic Form: A + B = C